# Cannot set cols in Asp.net MVC5 in TextAreaFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using this code but cols=20 keeps getting HTMLed. I have seen other solutions but they do not seem to be using syntax like "new { htmlAttributes = new { etc". I am new to MVC and this syntax was generated by Scaffolding. I do not have the knowledge to change this syntax. I was hoping to just add ', cols = "34"' as per below.

`<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpendDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SpendDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", cols = "34" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpendDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>`

The generated HTML is

`<textarea id="SpendDescription" rows="2" name="SpendDescription" htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, cols = 34 }" data-val-maxlength-max="200" data-val-maxlength="Must be less than 200 characters." data-val="true" cols="20"></textarea>`

Which is obviously wrong as "htmlattributes etc" became a string, 'form-control' did not become a class.

DARN! I just remembered that I changed the scaffolded code of EditorFor to TextAreaFor (a few days back) in order to have a text area. So I bet the code that passes htmlAttributes is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have one too many levels of `new {}` :)

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SpendDescription, new { @class = "form-control", cols = "34" })
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: Perfect - thank you.

A quick Q if possible here?
Why does class have an '@' in front of it but cols does not?

Comment: Because `class` is a reserved word in Razor :)

Comment: I'd love to but "Vote up requires 15 reputation".
So unfortunately I'm a disreputable person. :(

Comment: You should have 5 more now :)

Comment: @ThomasAJ I mean "accept" not vote up.  Click the tick under the voting buttons